# Confusion with weird C pointer behavior when passing through functions

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function int_make, which I use to convert int's into void pointers:

```
void* int_make(int id_num){
   int* id_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
   id_ptr = &id_num;
   void* id = id_ptr;
return id;}
```

I test this in main by the following

```
void * num_ptr = int_make(889);
printFunction(num_ptr);
```

where printFunction(num_ptr) casts the pointer to an int* pointer, then dereferences it

```
void printFunction(void * num_ptr){
printf("*(int*)num_ptr is %d\n", *(int*)num_ptr);}
```

and I get expected output

```
*(int*)num_ptr is 889
```

All good, until I call a different function, testD, (ignore unused parameters, all nonbuggy code has been removed)

```
void testD(void* ID, void* name, void* address, void* phone, struct hashtable* hashtable){
   printf("*(int*)phone is %d\n", *(int*)phone);}
```

the call in main:

```
void* phone= int_make(939209);
testD(id,name,addy,phone, table);
```

where I get the confusing result:

```
*(int)phone is 21985
```

This number (21985) is different every time I execute the code, so it must be a memory location, although I have no idea why my strategy (void* to int) worked on the 889 example (and many other tests, each rerun several times) and not this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
int* id_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Okay.  Now `id_ptr` points to one `int`'s worth of memory.  (Well, unless `malloc` fails.)

```
id_ptr = &id_num;
```

Whoops!  Now `id_ptr` points at `id_num`, the local parameter of the `int_make` function.  The previous value of `id_ptr`, the pointer returned by `malloc`, has just been lost.

```
void* id = id_ptr;
return id;
```

So now we're returning that pointer, the one that points to `id_num`.  This is a very bad practice!  `id_num` was the local parameter to the `int_make` function, but as soon as `int_make` returns, it's *gone*.  It might retain its value for a little while, so dereferencing `*(int*)num_ptr` in the caller might *seem* to work, but it's not at all guaranteed, and the more time goes by, the more likely it is that the memory formerly used by `id_num` (typically a location on the stack) will be reused for something else.

As @user3386109 already said in a comment, what you wanted to do here was not

```
id_ptr = &id_num;
```

but rather

```
*id_ptr = id_num;
```

This retains the malloc'ed pointer in `id_ptr`, and copies the value of `id_num` to that memory, so it sticks around as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing here or why, but if you want a pointer to an int as a void pointer, then you can just cast between the two cases. You can simply do:

```
void* int_make(int id_num) {
  void *ptrToVoid = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *(int*)ptrToVoid = id_num;
  return ptrToVoid;
}
```

I'm not sure this is a good idea. Having a `void*` that is "really" an `int*` is likely to lead to all sorts of mischief.